# Quaternion exponent and logarithm to non-standard base

Tags: exponentiation, quaternions

Given that the exponent of a quaternion $q = (w, \vec{v})$ with base $e$ is defined as

\begin{align}
e^q = e^w (\cos |\vec{v}| + \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|} \sin |\vec{v}|)
\end{align}

and the logarithm is defined as

\begin{align}
\ln q = (\ln |q|, \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|} \cos^{-1} \frac{w}{|q|})
\end{align}

I'd like to define exponentiation with a different (real scalar) base. I attempt to derive it as follows:

\begin{align}
b^q = e^{\ln b^q} = e^{q \ln b} \\
\end{align}

Similarly for logarithms:

\begin{align}
z = \log_b q \\
b^z = q \\
e^{z \ln b} = q \\
z \ln b = \ln q \\
z = \frac{\ln q}{\ln b}
\end{align}

Are these operations valid, and is that a reasonable way to define these two functions for quaternions?

I am particularly worried that $\ln e^q = q$ is not necessarily true in the last part.